# Two tables in two subfigures of a global figure: Align both vertically to top while keeping the subcaptions on the same level

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[!t]{0.45\textwidth}
   \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    $\phi(A)$ & $A$ \\
    \hline
    $a$ & $\{ a, e, i, o, u, y \}$ \\
    $b$ & $\{ x, z, q \}$ \\ 
    $c$ & $\{ w, v, r, s, t, c \}$ \\
    $d$ & $\{ b, d, f, g, h, j \}$ \\
    $e$ & $\{ k, l, m, n, p \}$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Reduction to five characters}
    \label{tbl:alpha5}
  \end{subfigure}
  ~
  \begin{subfigure}[!t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    $\phi(A)$ & $A$ \\
    \hline
    $a$ & $\{ a, e, i, o, u, y \}$ \\
    $b$ & $\{ x, z, q \}$ \\
    $c$ & $\{ w, v, r, s \}$ \\
    $d$ & $\{ t, c, b, d, f \}$ \\
    $e$ & $\{ g, h, j \}$ \\
    $f$ & $\{ k, l, m, n, p \}$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Reduction to six characters}
    \label{tbl:alpha6}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Alphabet reduction maps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to put them such that the headers of the two tables are on the same level, and both the subcaptions are on the same level too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you insert the instruction `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\null}` immediately after the final `\hline` of the first `tabular` environment. That way, the two `tabular` environments have the same number of rows and hence will align correctly automatically -- no need to add placement specifiers after `\begin{subfigure}{<width>}`.

```
...
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$\phi(A)$ & $A$ \\
\hline
$a$ & $\{ a, e, i, o, u, y \}$ \\
$b$ & $\{ x, z, q \}$ \\
$c$ & $\{ w, v, r, s, t, c \}$ \\
$d$ & $\{ b, d, f, g, h, j \}$ \\
$e$ & $\{ k, l, m, n, p \}$ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\null} % <-- new
\end{tabular}
...
```